# swagger-codegen is referencing a non-existent Java class

Tags: swagger, hyperledger-composer, swagger-codegen, hyperledger-explorer

I'm using swagger-codegen to create a Java stub around a Hyperledger Composer REST Server, but codegen is referencing a class that it hasn't generated.

Sample input:

```
 "responses": {
     "200": {
         "description": "Request was successful", 
         "schema": {
             "$ref": "#/definitions/Long"
         }
      }
 },
```

Checking the `definitions` section of the `swagger.json` file, there is no definition for Long.

The Java stub created includes this import, but there is no corresponding ModelLong class in that package:

```
import io.swagger.client.model.ModelLong;
```

The API stub code itself looks like this:

```
public ModelLong allowanceCreatePostAllowance(Allowance data) throws ApiException {
    ApiResponse<ModelLong> resp = allowanceCreatePostAllowanceWithHttpInfo(data);
    return resp.getData();
}
```

Is this a class I should expect to be writing myself or could there be some error in the mapping?